# Is there a T2i tethering operation from a laptop?

Tags: canon-550d, tethering

I'll be processing many images of artwork and saving files with various info like title and size and media.

I understand there are tethering options. I'm hoping I can hook the camera up directly from a laptop and record this info with the images directly. If I could also operate the camera, or even focus it from the laptop, even better.

Does Canon provide this out of the box or do I need some special software or cable?

I spotted this but I think all this functionality will be too much and I'd prefer something that costs less($175): http://www.breezesys.com/DSLRRemotePro/features.htm

Comment: Did you already try to use the USB cable and software that came with your camera?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use the Canon EOS Utility that comes with the camera in order to shoot tethered right outta the box. Once you've installed the Canon EOS Utility (on the CD that came with your camera), then a simple USB cable (should have also come with your camera in the box, but you might want to get a longer one if you want to get farther from your camera) will connect the two, and you're off and running...

The EOS Utility will give you complete control over the camera from your computer... Essentially if you can adjust it via the camera, you will be able to adjust it via your computer (shutter, ISO, aperture, white balance,timer, etc., etc., etc.). You can even engage 'Remote Live View' shooting so you can see what the camera is seeing, and remotely take pictures as well as video, should you desire...

Comment: Jay should I also then consider a USM lens for focusing? I don't think auto focus will be that beneficial for artwork, but if I can sit at the laptop and make sure everything is set right, it would be great not have to get up again to focus it. I wonder if the EOS utility can do that? Or can it do that somehow anyway with a standard lens?

Comment: USM won't make a huge difference one way or the other... Any AF lens will work. It's not that you get any *different* methods of focusing than if you were pushing the shutter button halfway down, or using the Live View AF, but I can see how using the Live View you could check the composition from your computer, trip the AF, and then fire. The Live View AF isn't *fast* by any means... But it'd work...

Answer (score 3):

Everything you mentioned are already doable using 'EOS Utility' (look in the CD that came with your camera). Once installed, connect your camera to your pc using the USB cable, open 'EOS Utility' and you're done!